# Method to Randomize Ordering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

This is an example of ordering the "values" according to created at in descension:

```
def index
    @values = Value.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Instead how can I randomize the index page's "values" every time it is refreshed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your database.

In MySQL this works:

```
Values.order('RAND')
```

In Postgres or SQLite use this:

```
Values.order('RANDOM()')
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general (not-db-related as well as not-suitable-for-production) solution you can simply do

```
Values.all.shuffle
```